# Как получить guid текстуры из материала?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Собственно сабж. Есть сферический материал, у него есть main_texture. Как получить guid назначеной текстуры ?

Comment: Это тот, который `Instance ID` ?

Comment: GUID - это собственно, что?